# Outlook won't sync emails to server

Tags: sync, microsoft-outlook-2013

I've imported some emails to my email account using Outlook 2013. When I look the inbox using Outlook I see them all (~3000), but when I access my email server directly there is just some of them (~450).

Is there a way to force Outlook to 'send back' these emails to my imap email server?

**Edit**:

There wasn't any changes in the server, so I decided to delete the emails I had imported there (I deleted direclty, not through Outlook).
Weirdly, after some time new emails started arriving ( about 100) and then stopped again. And every time I delete emails, a few more arrive (~30)...

Comment: Judging by the deleting of mails making a difference, I'd check the mail server for space. Could be you're near the limit of your mailbox allowance

Comment: Is this an Exchange server or something else?

Comment: I thought about space, but it's not the case, there is plenty of space. The migration is from GoDaddy to Uol Host. 
I don't know if a server can choke if it receives too many emails at once, for instance...

Answer (score 0):

The email server will not show all your e-mails until your local e-mails are uploaded to the server. You are seeing some, but not all because your 3,000 emails have not been uploaded to the server.

Your only option is to use the Send/Receive and do a Send/Receive All option. On the bottom of Outlook, you should see a progress bar.